# Using DMD in two separate steps: Linking 64-bit (Linux)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, 64-bit, d

I'm running on 64-bit Ubuntu, and trying to get DMD v2.052 to work with Code::Blocks. The problem is, Code::Blocks does compiling and linking in two separate steps, and I can't seem to get around that. My compiler flags (for this project) are -m64, and my linker flags are all the ones supplied in dmd.conf. However, I get errors when I try to do this, like

```
Linking console executable: bin/Debug/Gossamer
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/me/devl/sfml2/bindings/d/lib/libdsfml-system.a when searching for -ldsfml-system
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldsfml-system
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/me/devl/sfml2/bindings/d/lib/libdsfml-graphics.a when searching for -ldsfml-graphics
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldsfml-graphics
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/me/devl/sfml2/bindings/d/lib/libdsfml-audio.a when searching for -ldsfml-audio
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldsfml-audio
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/me/devl/sfml2/bindings/d/lib/libdsfml-window.a when searching for -ldsfml-window
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldsfml-window
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I compiled the DSFML libs myself, using `dmd -m64 -lib [library source code files]`, and there it wasn't in two steps, so I know they're fine. It seems ld doesn't like them, for some reason. Can somebody help?

Comment: Do those libraries work if you compile a test app manually?

Comment: I haven't been able to get the libraries working with anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing the compile from the command line using just DMD. If that works I think there is a flag that will cause DMD to print the command line for the link command. From that you should be able to tell what you need Code::Blocks to do differently.

Comment: Yup; I was missing some critical linker flags (most importantly -m elf_x86_64).